# No output when reading file in textarea

Tags: java, swing, file, io, jtextarea

I have modified this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/SwingFileChooserDemo.htm) to read txt files in a text area, but I seem to get no output in the textarea.

My code:

```
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String line;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                String token = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
        textArea.read( br, null );

    } 
    catch (IOException r) {
        r.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) br.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

i seem to also not have any output in the console.

Comment: The best way to get a decent answer is to create a simple program that will compile and run for us, that will demonstrate your problem, and then post it here in your question, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i know i have a problem with this line
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
if you can tell me if this actually is correct to read a full path or not that would be grateful of you

Comment: Why are you so confident the problem is in that line? It seems correct to me.

Comment: @ Outflorks: as I cannot compile nor run your code, I'm at a loss to know what would be best for you. I would have to create an SSCCE myself to solve this for you, but I'd much rather *you* put in this effort for us, since it is *your* question after all.

Comment: As a style preference:  You should close the reader inside of the first `try` block.  Or better yet, use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Use [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) instead.  It is likely to be more reliable.  Now I look at the code more closely, it seem the data needs a `JTable`.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is here:

```
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String line;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            textArea.read(br, null);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line,
                        " ");
                while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String token = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException r) {
            r.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: textArea.read() line should come before reading all data from stream.  In your case br.readLine() reads all data and flush it from buffer so you got empty buff. reader and that's why you got nothing in you text box. Note: always remember that buffer maintains data in memory (RAM) until you read it.

Comment: It's correct, since the way he posted, seems the reader was at the EOF position, however, I recall him saying that on console, he was not getting any output, so I think he was referring to the `System.out.println` part...

Comment: You can point out that above program prints nothing on command line because buffer is already flushed by textare's read method

Comment: Yes, but not on his example. On his, the output should have been dumped to the console (since he reads the buffer for that first) and none on the textArea. That would be the expected behavior, however, he said that he was not getting anything on either, console or textArea.

Comment: that's the correct answer, thank you
although i had another logical error, but still this line :textArea.read(br, null); position was my problem